# How to change the color of rectangular node based on number of agents in the node in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

Is there a way to change the color of my rectangular nodes (represented as resource pool) based on number of resources idle/busy. For example, if I have 10 resource pool available, then the home node will be green, if I have 5 available resource out of 10 then the home node will be yellow, and if it is less than 3 then the home node will be red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an event that is triggered every second, or every 10 seconds, or every time a resource is seized or released (check the actions on seize and release on the resourcepool block)

```
if(resurcePool.idle()<3){
   node.setFillColor(red);
}else{
   node.setFillColor(green);
}
```